# Estimate $m$ using Chebyschev inequality

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_{125}$ be i.i.d.random variables with binomial distribution with parameter $\left(8,\dfrac1{200}\right)$. We define a random variable $S$ as
$$
S(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^{125}X_i(\omega)$$
and$$
A=\min\{m\in\mathbb{N}:P(S\le m)\ge0.96\}.
$$
I have to estimate $m$ using Chebyschev inequality.

I state that since $S$ is defined as a sum of binomial variables, so $S\sim Bin(8\cdot125, 1/200) $ so $E[S]=5$ and $Var(S)=199/40$. Now I know that Chebyschev inequality is used to find the number of values that can be more than a certain distance from the mean, but I don't know how to apply it to find $m$.
Any ideas or hints?

Comment: Let $\mu=\mathbb{E} S$. Then $\Pr[S\leq m]=1-\Pr[S>m]=1-\Pr[S-\mu>m-\mu]\geq 1-\Pr[|S-\mu|>m-\mu]$. Chebyschev tells you how to upper bound $\Pr[|S-\mu|>t]$, so you can now use this to lower bound $\Pr[S\leq m]$

Comment: @Munchhausen : so now i have that $1-P(|S-E[S]|>m-E[S])\ge 1- \frac{Var(S)}{(m-E[S])^2}\le 0.96 $ ?

Comment: Yes, you have $\Pr[S\leq m]\geq 1-{\text{Var}(S)\over(m-\mathbb{E} S)^2}$, and you would like to show $\Pr[S\leq m]\geq 0.96$. So solve the equation $1-{\text{Var}(S)\over (m-\mathbb{E} S)^2}=0.96$ for $m$. Note that this will only give an upper bound on $A$ since we have inequalities floating around, but this is the estimate they're looking for

Comment: @Munchhausen I solve the equation and i obtain $16.15$ and $-6.15$ so in my case $m=17$ is right?

Comment: That's what I get! However, you can do much better than this by using Chernoff instead of Chebyshev.